# Amazon RDS SQL Server set timezone at database level

Tags: amazon-rds

We recently  moved the database to Amazon RDS SQL Server. We have some difficulties with the date times (timezone). By default RDS provides UTC date. Is there any way to overwrite / manipulate the local timezone at database level in SQL Server. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance,
SqlLover

Comment: See my answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853530/amazon-rds-are-there-workarounds-to-change-a-database-time-zone-in-sql-server/31978866#31978866][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853530/amazon-rds-are-there-workarounds-to-change-a-database-time-zone-in-sql-server/31978866#31978866

Answer (score 5):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=161339

> The time zone is currently not modifiable.  There is indeed a Parameter value in rds-describe-db-parameters called "default_time_zone" but it's marked as not modifiable.