# Set the timezone to UTC + 8 at the Amazon RDS service

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, amazon-web-services

I have implemented a system in my internal server

When insert record there is a current date field which is the timestamp and by default is the current time.

It works fine on local server until recently I need to move the database to Amazon RDS, it is set UTC instead of UTC + 8.

So , instead of changing every query in my models PHP , are there any more convenient way to adapt the changes?

I am using codeigniter and after some searching , it suggest using procedure like this:

[Amazon RDS - are there workarounds to change a database time zone in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853530/amazon-rds-are-there-workarounds-to-change-a-database-time-zone-in-sql-server/31978866#31978866)

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE mysql.init_connect_procedure () 
IF  NOT(POSITION(‘rdsadmin@’ IN user()) = 1) 
THEN SET SESSION time_zone = 'America/New_York';
END IF |
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is it that need to be call everytime I run the query? so that how to modify the codeigniter Model class to run that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this may be it help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19075291/4684564

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with codeigniter and I find that using the php date_default_timezone_set('') solved the problem for me.
Hope this helps.

Comment: so for the create date do I need to insert using date() ? I perfer not to edit like this as there are a lot of queries thanks

Comment: If i understand correctly, your actual requirement is independent of codeigniter. If it is, then does the link in the comment above by Keval answer your question?